# How do I avoid this NullPointerException when connecting remotely to a JBoss AS via JMX from VisualVM?

Tags: java, profiling, nullpointerexception, jmx, visualvm

#### Problem:

When I connect via VisualVM and supply the correct credentials, the program seems to wait a bit (either processing or waiting for the connection), then errors out with this an exception.  The connection does not seem to get added correctly after this exception is throw:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Illegal null argument
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectionNotification.<init>(JMXConnectionNotification.java:152)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RMIClientCommunicatorAdmin.gotIOException(RMIConnector.java:1444)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.isInstanceOf(RMIConnector.java:1062)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$CheckerInvocationHandler.invoke(JmxModelImpl.java:598)
    at $Proxy7.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(ManagementFactory.java:616)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jmx.JvmMXBeansFactory$JvmMXBeansImpl.getMXBean(JvmMXBeansFactory.java:383)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jmx.JvmMXBeansFactory$JvmMXBeansImpl.getRuntimeMXBean(JvmMXBeansFactory.java:356)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplication.getPid(JmxApplication.java:84)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.JvmstatModelProvider.getMonitoredVm(JvmstatModelProvider.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.JvmstatModelProvider.createModelFor(JvmstatModelProvider.java:71)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.JvmstatModelProvider.createModelFor(JvmstatModelProvider.java:45)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.model.ModelFactory.getModel(ModelFactory.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jvmstat.JvmstatModelFactory.getJvmstatFor(JvmstatModelFactory.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JRockitJvmProvider.createModelFor(JRockitJvmProvider.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JRockitJvmProvider.createModelFor(JRockitJvmProvider.java:42)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.model.ModelFactory.getModel(ModelFactory.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.jvm.JvmFactory.getJVMFor(JvmFactory.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.addJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:292)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.access$100(JmxApplicationProvider.java:73)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider$3$1.run(JmxApplicationProvider.java:408)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1424)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1968)
```

#### Background:

I am using VisualVM to do some simple profiling work.  I am running jboss-4.2.2.GA on Windows.

In my `run.bat` file I have:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<myport>
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

In the JMX password file I created, I have enabled a role with read only access, and have made sure read access is set appropriately on that file.

I can connect to the server on `localhost:<myport>` via JMX.  The username and password match the role and password in my JMX password config file.  Using different credentials or a different password doesn't work, so this is definitely set up correctly.

I have set up a general firewall exception in my domain for `java.exe`.  When I don't have this exception, I cannot connect at all to the server.  When I have it enabled, I can connect remotely to `myport` via telnet, and I get a password dialog when I try to connect remotely via VisualVM.

I tried looking through the code referenced in the exception stack trace.  As far as I can tell, `connectionId` is probably `null` when constructing `JMXConnectionNotification`.  I can't tell why because I haven't bothered trying to run this in a debugger.

#### Is there anything I have configured incorrectly?  How do I get past this error?

---

*Edit:*

I just tried connecting remotely with JConsole and I'm getting a totally different error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1;
```

I don't have any entries in my hosts file on the client machine, as some things on the net have suggested WRT this error.  Is this indicative of a different problem, or are they related?

Comment: Is your firewall exception limited only to 'myport'? JMX uses dynamically generated connections in addition to 'myport'.

Comment: On the server, I have it set up to be open for Java.exe for the domain (no ports specified, so I believe this means all ports).  On the client side I tried temporarily disabling the Windows firewall entirely.  I will try disabling the firewall on the server and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm getting the same thing and can't seem to get past it.  Disabling authentication doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, it was helpful to set following property:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.2
```

where `192.168.1.2` is actual IP address of monitored server.

Answer (score 0):

These are the entries I have in run.bat and it is working fine. May be missing authenticate=true causing the issue.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<myport>
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: I read somewhere that you couldn't remote without auth enabled, so I enabled it.  However I was having the same problem before I enabled auth.

Comment: Just checked the source of JMXConnectionNotification, the comment there is,  if (type == null || source == null || connectionId == null)
                    throw new NullPointerException("Illegal null argument");

Comment: I don't know how JMX itself works, so I don't know what type, source, or connection id actually are.  But tracing through the code that calls it makes it seem like the only thing that *could* be null out of those is `connectionId`.  That's why I mentioned it in my question.  Any thoughts?  Seems like its making a virtual call to whatever custom component is referenced by the `connection` field to get that value.